# Azure IoT Hub module specified in deployment but not deploying

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have a IoT Edge Module that I want to deploy on my IoT Edge device.

In VSCode, I right-clicked on the `deployment.template.json`and then selected `Build and Push IoT Edge Solution`. The module has been built and pushed to my container registry. Then I right-clicked on the generated `deployment.json` and selected `Create Deployment for Single Device` and selected my IoT Edge device.

From VSCode, I have the following output:

```
[Edge] Start deployment to device [RaspberryPi]
[Edge] Deployment succeeded.
```

On the Azure Portal, I can see the module in the list of the device's modules. Its status is :

```
| SPECIFIED IN DEPLOYMENT | REPORTED BY DEVICE | RUNTIME STATUS |
|-------------------------|--------------------|----------------|
|           Yes           |         No         |       --       |
```

But when I look at directly on my device, the deployment didn't start.

I checked the log with `journalctl -u iotedge` and I found nothing related to the deployment. Normally I should have something like `starting pulling module xxx`, `Successfully pulled module xxx`, `Starting module xxx`, `Successfully started module xxx`.

Does someone have an idea of how to solve this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Please check the Common issues and resolutions for Azure IoT Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot and see if it helps to resolve the issue.